# JCE Editor not working on Joomla

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0, joomla3.2, joomla-community-builder

I installed Joomla 3.6.2 and I just add the text editor JCE editor and its enabled but when I went to article the editor is not active. I tried a different way to fix but no luck. Is there anyone had the same issue and can help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to `Global Configuration` from `System` menu. Then change the value of `Default Editor` option to JCE.

#### Alternate Way

Go to `User Manager` and open your account. In `Basic Settings` tab change the value of `Editor` to JCE

Answer (score 1):

After making the change in the user profile, I put it back to default. I then went to Joomla Control Panel, CONFIGURATION, Global and changed to "Editor - None", Save. Then went back changed it back to "Editor - JCE", Save & Close. Now the JCE Editor works with all Users.

I then went to my live site (above done on my test site first) and only made the change/save/change in the Global configuration. Issue fixed.

I guess setting it to none, then back again to the JCE Editor fixed the issue.